# Spectron available methods doesn't work properly

Tags: electron, webdriver-io, spectron

I'm using spectron on webdriverIO and try to avoid `client.pause()` method to wait and used `client.waitForExist`, `waitForWindowLoading`, `waitUnitlText` but the application closes very quick and I don't want to pass the implicit wait

can someone guide me towards the right direction to achieve it?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not use webdriverio apis directly. You may have to be using the apis from Spectron which are listed in the below link.

https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron#clientwaituntilwindowloadedtimeout

Here is another link.

https://github.com/eostrom/spectron/blob/webdriverio-5/test/commands-test.js